# Multiple different relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I'm still trying to figure out the logic behind various different relationship types in Rails.

In this use-case, I'm trying to build a list of `Service`s, each of which has one `Owner` and multiple `Provider`s. Owners and Providers should each be associated with a `Country` (*i.e.* their registered jurisdiction), while the Services may have different Countries (*i.e.* the country/-ies where the services are actually performed).

The models I've come up with are therefore the following:

```ruby
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owners
  has_many :recipients
end
```

```ruby
class Owner < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  has_many   :recipients, through: :services
end
```

```ruby
class Recipient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  has_many   :owners, through: :services
end
```

```ruby
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :recipient
end
```

Meanwhile, the migrations are as follows (they're spread in four segregated files, but I've merged them into one single snippet for brevity):

```ruby
class CreateDatabase < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :countries do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :owners do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :country, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :recipients do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :country, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :services do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :country, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :owner, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :recipient, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm still unsure if this is correct, particularly the respective instructions in the models. Indeed, I'm having a hard time figuring out who `belongs_to` to whom, and who `has_one` (or many) of whom.

Is this indeed correct, or is there a better way to proceed?

For what it's worth, I'm using ruby 3.2.1 with rails 7.0.4.

Comment: Besides you missed `has_many :services` in Owner and Recipient (so `has_many :through` won't work), it looks ok.

Comment: Where is this Provider that you're writing about?

Comment: As @mikdiet pointed out you need to add `has_many :services` to `Owner` and `Recipient` (you could also add it to `Country` if you wanted). Other than that there is nothing technically wrong with your schema or your ORM setup, whether or not this is correct for your specific use case is a question only you can really answer.